# Data for income distributions

Tags: data-request, statistics, inequality, wealth

Knowing the average income per capita or the median income is a rather poor economical indicator of a country, even when given in PPP\$. Knowing the (dimension-less) [Gini index](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SI.POV.GINI) is somehow better, but it's too abstract a quantity and doesn't - as a number - tell too much. The Lorenz curve from which the Gini index is derived contains a bit more information but it is still hard to grasp: "What exactly do these curves tell me?"

[image]

The most objective and intuitive way of displaying income statistics possibly is just plotting the number of people over income (blue) and the accumulated income per income group (silver):

[image]

Unfortunately I find such plots only rarely. What I am looking for is a database where I can find the appropriate data (e.g. relative sizes of 10 or 20 income groups) for ideally all countries of the world.

The World Bank seems to publish only [income shares held by the kth 20%](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/world-development-indicators/themes/poverty-and-inequality.html#featured-indicators_1) which is better than nothing and does allow to draw Lorenz curves. But it would not allow to draw more detailed income distributions.

**Where do I find such data: number of capita per income (with appropriate income bins: < 10%, < 20%, .... > 90% of the average (or median) income).**

Comment: From your question it sounds like you have Lorenz curve for each country. If you have that and total population, you can back out the income histogram for a country.

Comment: @Art: Can you give me a hint how to do this, e.g. given the income share of the five quintils by 2.4%, 4.8%, 8.2%, 16.5%, 68.2% as for South Africa in 2014 (according to the [World Bank](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/world-development-indicators/themes/poverty-and-inequality.html#featured-indicators_1) - resulting in a [Gini index of 63.0](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SI.POV.GINI). How would I calculate or estimate from these numbers the percentage of people/households with 20%, 50%, 100%, 200%, 500%, 1,000%, 2,000% and 5,000% of the average (or median) income?

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is the PDF of your hisogram. The lorenz curve is just the CDF of the function, and you can take derivative to back out the PDF. This requires you to have a reasonably fine-binned Lorenz curve though, like percentile, instead of quintiles.